# Getting error while installing the DreamHouse in salesforce

Tags: community, managed-package, trailhead

Developer Beginner > Platform Development Basics > Get Started with Salesforce Platform

As indicated in the instruction, I created new Trealhead Playground and tried to install DreamHouse app. Then I encountered a problem. I appreciate if someone can guide me to at where I should look into to resolve the issue.Getting the attached error while trying to install the DreamHouse package.No solution found so far.Looking for help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a class named `Test` in your org, which is causing compilation errors. Rename or delete the class named `Test` in order to complete the installation. As a general best practice, you should avoid naming classes the same as standard library objects, such as `Test`, `Schema`, `Account`, `JSON`, etc.